# Securing access to AWS Lambda through API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am creating simple REST API using AWS Lambda and API Gateway.
This API will be used by external services (scripts), but I want to secure access to the API so it won't be accessible publicly. Also I want to restrict some services from accessing parts of the API and be able to revoke their permissions at any time.

API example:

- **CatsLambda** -> *GET /cats*
- **DogsLambda** -> *GET /dogs*
- **FishLambda** -> *GET /fish*

External scripts:

- **CatsScript** can access */cats* but not */dogs* and */fish*
- **MammalScript** can access */cats* and */dogs* but not */fish*

I think I need to create some kind of users for my scripts and use them for accessing API.
I was thinking of using Cognito but I am no longer sure if this kind of setup is possible.

Do you have any ideas? Do I have to create my own authorizer on API Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use either Custom Authorizer or AWS Cognito user pools.

If you are going ahead with custom authorizer, you can create a lambda function to do the authorization part. A sample code from AWS documentation is like follows

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
    var token = event.authorizationToken;
    // Call oauth provider, crack jwt token, etc.
    // In this example, the token is treated as the status for simplicity.

    switch (token.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'allow':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'deny':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'unauthorized':
            callback("Unauthorized");   // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
            break;
        default:
            callback("Error: Invalid token"); 
    }
};

var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    var authResponse = {};

    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    if (effect && resource) {
        var policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; // default version
        policyDocument.Statement = [];
        var statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; // default action
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource;
        policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }

    // Can optionally return a context object of your choosing.
    authResponse.context = {};
    authResponse.context.stringKey = "stringval";
    authResponse.context.numberKey = 123;
    authResponse.context.booleanKey = true;
    return authResponse;
}
```

You can read more and how to implement custom authorizers [using this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html).

If you are using User pools, you can integrate API with user pool. You can follow the steps defined in [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) to do the integration. Quoting from the site,

> **To create a user pool authorizer using the API Gateway console**
>
> - Create a new API or select an existing API in API Gateway.
> - From the main navigation pane, choose Authorizers under the specified API.
> - Under Authorizers, choose Create and then choose Cognito User Pool Authorizer.
>
> To configure this authorizer:
>
> - Choose a region for Cognito region.
> - For Cognito User Pool, choose an available user pool.
> - The Authorizer name field will be automatically populated with the chosen user pool name. However, you can customize it if you want to.
> - The Identity token source field will be set to method.request.header.Authorization by default. However, you can
>     customize it if you want to. Using the default, Authorization will be
>     the name of the incoming request header to contain an API caller's
>     identity token.
> - Optionally, type a regular expression in the App client ID regex field to validate client IDs associated with the user pool.
> - Choose Create to finish integrating the user pool with the API.
> - Having created the authorizer, you can, optionally, test it by supplying an identity token provisioned from the user pool.
>
> **To enable a user pool authorizer on methods**
>
> - Choose (or create) a method of your API.
> - Choose Method Request.
> - Under Authorization Settings, choose the edit icon by the Authorization field.
> - Choose one of the available Amazon Cognito User Pool authorizers from the drop-down list.
> - Choose the check-mark icon to save the settings.
>
> Repeat these steps for other methods of your choosing.

[Update] Updating the answer with Ashan's suggested methodology.

> Another option is to use Cognito user groups with IAM authorization at API gateway. Access permission can be given through policies which are assigned to roles linked with groups.

Comment: Another option is to use cognito user groups with iam authorization at api gateway. Access permission can be given through policies which are assigned to roles linked with groups.

Comment: @Ashan thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer with your method.